# Why am I getting an empty WHERERAW KNEX object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
async show(req,res){
  const name = req.body.productname
   const schedule = await knex.select('name').whereRaw('name = ?', name).table('appointments')

console.log(schedule)
   res.status(200).json()
 }
```

I would like to receive all the data in the table using the name as a filter

Comment: seems  your `appointments` doesn't have any matching row, check database once. (btw you are using `productname`  in `appointments` table,  isn't you suppose to be looking up `products` table instead .. or its just bad variable name you gave)